# Django pass parameters using HttpResponseRedirect Reverse

Tags: python, django

I want to redirect the user to a sign-up page upon completing an "easy register" form on a landing page, so I am required to pass the landing page name, cell phone and user's email that they input in the "easy register" form. But I keep getting this error:

```
Reverse for 'signup_page' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'landing_name': u'promotion-title-1', 'cell_phone': u'1111111', 'user_email': u'aaq@aaa.com'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

I have searched through some of the solutions but I still can't solve this.

This is the urls.py:

```
(r'^signup/(?P<landing_name>[-\w]+)/(?P<cell_phone>[-\w]+)/(?P<user_email>[\w.%+-]+@[A-Za- 
z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})/$', signup_page, {'template_name':'promotion/signup_page.html'},
'signup_page'),
```

views.py:

```
url = reverse('signup_page', kwargs={'landing_name': landing_name, 'cell_phone': cell_phone, 'user_email': email, })
return HttpResponseRedirect(url)
```

signup_page views.py:

```
def signup_page(request, landing_name, cell_phone, user_email):

    landing = get_object_or_404(LandingPage, url=landing_name)

    data = {
        'email':user_email,
    }

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = User_SignUp_Form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['email']

            if form.cleaned_data['password_1'] != form.cleaned_data['password_2']:
                password_error = 'passwords do not match each other'
            else:
                password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

                try:
                    #check for duplicate username
                    User.objects.get(username=username)
                    username_error = 'username already exist'
                except:
                    #initial creation of user object
                    try:
                        password = form.cleaned_data['password_1']
                        User.objects.create_user(username,
                                                 username,
                                                 password,
                        )
                        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                        UserProfile.objects.create_user(user=user, cell_phone=cell_phone,)
                        next = request.GET.get('next')
                        if next is None:
                            next = '/'
                        return redirect('/account/thankyou/?next=%s'%next)

                    except:
                        pass

    else:
        form = User_SignUp_Form(initial=data)

    return render_to_response("promotion/signup_page.html", locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: what's happen if you type directly the url in the browser (signup/promotion-title-1/1111111/aaq@aaa.com/) ? Do you get 404 with the list of all patterns ?

Comment: return HttpResponseRedirect("/page/signup/" + landing_name + "/" + cell_phone + "/" + email + "/")

I use that for now and it works.